# Select next record on datasheet subform from separate form?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have 2 forms. 1 subform.

The main form, MainFormF, has a subform which is hooked up to a query that takes data from a table and outputs it into a datasheet. Lets call this subform MainSubformF.

The 2nd form is loaded from a button on MainFormF. It has 2 buttons, previous and next. How do I attach these buttons to switch the next/previous record HIGHLIGHTED in the datasheet subform?

[image: Highlighted record]

As you can see, that is what it looks like highlighted. It turns blue, if you didn't know.

The code I currently use but doesn't switch the selected records at all is this:

```
Private Sub Command65_Click()
On Error GoTo new_Err

Forms!MainformF!MainSubformF.SetFocus 'sets the focus to MainSubformF
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNew
new_Err:
End Sub
```

For the button to open up the More Info form, it takes information from a text box (lets name it InfoTxt) with this as it's control source:

```
=[MainSubformF].[Form]![ProjectID]
```

I am thinking I can do something with that variable, like add +1 to it so when the button is clicked it adds +1 to the ProjectID? I don't think that will work now that I am typing this out, but I'll keep this here in case I am right... though I am thinking further into it and ProjectID's aren't always +1, as in case a record was deleted it may go 1,2,3,5,6 and if you get to 3 then click next it'll do nothing as it'll go to 4 not 5.

Answer (score 0):

I simply don't have time to write out a complete answer, but Dev Ashish is a well-respected developer in the Access community and he devised a way to determine which records have been selected.  My guess is you'll need to bookmark them somehow.  Start with this Sub that Dev wrote:

[Determine selected records in datasheet view](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0033.htm)

Comment: Would this work for using a separate form to control the selection; if so do I put the code on the separate form or the main one?

Comment: Looks like this is used on a main form and will allow you to determine which records in a subform are selected.  You'll have to modify it to instead bookmark a record, and then the "Prev" and "Next" buttons would move from bookmark to bookmark.  I'm just throwing ideas out there, I'm actually swamped at work and can't even consider offering more help than that.

Comment: Looked into it and actually it confused me. I usually can read code pretty well, but this seems to be way too advanced for me. I can understand a little bit of it, but then it gets convoluted and I got lost. Gah.